# Word for “by no choice of your own” such as your skin colour

Tags: synonyms

Is there a word for something you can’t change about yourself?

Comment: ***genetic**?*, ***congenital**?*, ***inherent / intrinsic**?* What about being obese because you can't control your appetite? Or if you're just so ***lazy*** you can't do anything about your laziness?

Comment: 'Nonelective' is perhaps the most semantically appropriate synonym of 'compulsory', · 'mandatory', 'nonvoluntary', 'obligatory' ... but still doesn't sound too good here.

Comment: Please provide the sentence you'll use this word in.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks, it’s now on the record.

Comment: @marcellothearcane see fumblefingers :)

Answer (score 3):

At least three terms come to mind: my skin colour is *natural*, my nature is *innate*, my appearance is *inborn*.

Comment: I like the word innate

Comment: That too would be my first choice. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

"Inherent" works as a qualifier for that kind of thing.

> **Inherent (adj):** existing as a natural or basic part of something.
>
> Example: There are dangers/risks inherent in almost every sport.
>
>  [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/inherent)

Comment: Inherent is a great, though @fumblefingers mentioned it in the comments.

Comment: @GeorgeMack: Comments are not "answers".

Answer (score 0):

As an atheist, I hesitate to suggest that the English language adjective for this is

> [God-given](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/god-given?q=God-given)

> e.g. She has a God-given talent…

meaning she was born with it.

(This does have an alternative use that does not fit this case, but should be obvious from the context.)

Of course the most obvious biblical expression is about leopards and spots, but it my be politic to leave the Ethiopians out of this.